# GPU possible issue on graphic card to Install GNOME or Unity - Ubuntu server 16.04.6 LTS (amd64)

Tags: 64-bit, process, interface

I am looking for advice on the sequence to validate the current status of a server and probably uninstall components and install new components.

I am new to this process, the server is supplied by a provider that said it comes with X pre-installed, Is X a desktop interface?, Do I need to uninstall before installing the default desktop interface?, Is Unity the default desktop interface for this ubuntu version? Sorry guys, this is too basic but I have found lots of info on the web and it is confusing, so I decided to ask the experts. Here is the information about the GPU.

When I installed GNOME I got a flashing screen. When I installed Unity a couple of messages popped up, but after answering them, I just got a dark screen.

Thanks in advance.

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial
Architecture:   amd64
```

```
ubuntu@mcahsum:~$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display:0
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GD 5446
       vendor: Cirrus Logic
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller rom
       configuration: driver=cirrus latency=0
       resources: irq:0 memory:f0000000-f1ffffff memory:fe110000-fe110fff memory:fe100000-fe10ffff
  *-display:1
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GP102 [TITAN Xp]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 5
       bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:11 memory:fd000000-fdffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f2000000-f3ffffff ioport:c000(size=128) memory:fe080000-fe0fffff
```

1 Image 1 shows a flashing screen after installing GNOME:

[image: Flashing screen]

2 After installing unity two messages are displayed, the first one says:

[image]

Your screen, graphics card, and input device settings could not be detected correctly. You will need to configure this yourself. Press OK, after pressing Ok I got the second message that says:

Try running the default graphic mode  [ENTER], here a select option 'default graphic mode', and after that, I don't see the graphic interface, I just see a dark screen asking for a password.

Comment: FYI:  GNOME (https://ubuntugnome.org/ http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) being a flavor in the 16.04 cycle is now EOL being supported for only 3 years. Yes Unity was the default desktop, and it along with no desktop (server), default desktop (Unity) and Kylin (flavor sponsored by Canonical for 16.04 only) still receive security patches (though some GNOME software is identical to that found in Unity thus will receive upgrades). If used online, GNOME may not be the wisest choice..   You also haven't included any picture/images; yet refer to them.

Comment: Images are uploaded now